# how to zip the file using ionic library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zip

I have done this one for backup my database
its working fine ....

```
    private void backupDatabase()
    {

        txtbackup.AppendText("Starting Backup...");    
        Process sd = null;
        const  string backupcmd = @"C:\wamp\www\access\mysqldump.exe";
        string filepath = @"C:\folder\Access\";
        string dbHost = "local";
        string dbuser = "root";
        string dbName = "access";
        string backupName = "Backup.sql";
        ProcessStartInfo r1 = new ProcessStartInfo(backupcmd, string.Format("-h {0} -u {1} {2} -r {3}", dbHost, dbuser, dbName, backupName));


        r1.CreateNoWindow = true;
        r1.WorkingDirectory = filepath;
        r1.UseShellExecute = false;
        r1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        r1.RedirectStandardInput = false;

        sd = Process.Start(r1);
         sd.WaitForExit();

        if (!sd.HasExited)
        {
             sd.Close();
        }
        sd.Dispose();
        r1 = null;
        sd = null;
        txtbackup.Clear();
        txtbackup.AppendText("Backup is Finished");

    }
```

its working fine ...but i want to store the backup.sql as a  zip file in this path

```
@"C:\folder\Access\";
```

i have got this  library Ionic.Zip.Reduced  but i dont know how to zip the file and stored in the given path....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library is pretty simple to use :

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFile("Backup.sql");

    zip.Save(@"C:\folder\Access\"Backup.zip");
}
```

And even [their homepage](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) contains samples good enough for your use.

Comment: How would you do this for two files needing a separate ZIP each?

Answer (score -1):

You should use this compression library or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280.aspx) one may be an option?

Comment: Yes, excellent suggestion.  Let's roll our own implementation of the .zip file format.